# SVG to Shape (EaselJS)

Tags: javascript, canvas, shapes, easeljs

In EaselJS only shapes can became a masks, so I was wondering if I can convert somehow SVG made in Inkscape into EaselJS, I found this great tool - http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/ that allows me to convert SVG to Context, but is there a way/tool to easily convert SVG to EaselJS Shape (this is almost the same object as Shape in Flash/AS3)? I need only a basic shape like this:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="776.4032"
   height="405.87927"
   id="svg1383">
  <defs
     id="defs1385" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata1388">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="translate(15.455332,-13.016229)"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       d="m 1193.5963,82.437378 a 369.81683,206.47517 0 1 1 -739.63371,0 A 369.81683,206.47517 0 1 1 1193.5963,82.437378 Z"
       transform="matrix(1.0497132,0,0,0.98287671,-491.98585,134.93009)"
       id="mask"
       style="fill:#008000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;display:inline" />
  </g>
  <g
     transform="translate(15.455332,-13.016229)"
     id="layer2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Try Fabric.js -- http://fabricjs.com

Answer (score 0):

After you generate your js code on webpage you gave, you can override function in shape called [draw](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/files/.._src_easeljs_display_DisplayObject.js.html#l581). Just paste generated code in your function and you should be able to see your image.

Example code:

```
  var s = new createjs.Shape();
  // this is important because if we dont change graphics our overriden
  // function wont be called.
  s.graphics.beginFill("#FF0000").rect(0, 0, 75, 100);

  //save old draw function
  var oldDraw = s.draw;
  // here we switch draw funciton to the one generated from svg file
  s.draw = this.draw;
  // draw our model on cache
  s.cache(0, 0, 66, 113, 2);
  // and now we can back to old drawing function
  s.draw = oldDraw;
```

Comment: I tried this: the SVG is displayed on the canvas, but unfortunately the clipping is done for the original rect. Leaving out the s.graphics.beginFill() etc. does not help. Any help would be really appreciated...